# detach single belongsToMany relationship

Tags: eloquent

I need to detach a single belongs to many relationship however I can't figure it out. Below is how I have got the `belongsToMany` relationship setup:

`WebsiteController`

```php
/** @var User $user */
$user = \Auth::user();

$favorites = $user->favoriteWebsites;
```

`User`

```php
/**
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function favoriteWebsites(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Website::class, 'planner_favorite_websites');
}
```

When a user clicks a button I will have access to the website ID associated with the pivot table. Tables are setup like follows:

```
websites
id, name, code

users
id, fname, lname

planner_favorite_websites
id, user_id, website_id
```

How can I use the website ID to detach just that single website from the current user logged in. So I will have the Website ID and User ID.

Obviously I could do a simple `where(['website_id' => 0, 'user_id' => 0])` but this doesn't seem the correct way to use relationships.

Comment: I guess it would be something simple like `$user->favoriteWebsites()->detach($website_id);` or there is any other issue you have

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Unfortunately that doesn't work. No errors, just returns `0` so no rows affected.